# Extracting data from a text file to an output file

Tags: python, file, text, extract

I have alot of files which names are just number. (Starting from 1 to whatever is the maximum number) and each of these files are similar to each other by their "tags" (ObjectID =, X =, Y =, etc.), but the values after those tags are not the same at all.

I wanted to make my job easier from manually copy/pasting the data from one file to another and made a small script using Python (since I am slightly experienced in it).

This is the full script:

```
import os

BASE_DIRECTORY = 'C:\Users\Tom\Desktop\TheServer\scriptfiles\Objects'
output_file = open('output.txt', 'w')
output = {}
file_list = []

for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in os.walk(BASE_DIRECTORY):
    for f in filenames:
        if 'txt' in str(f):
            e = os.path.join(str(dirpath), str(f))
            file_list.append(e)

for f in file_list:
    print f
    txtfile = open(f, 'r')
    output[f] = []
    for line in txtfile:
        if 'ObjectID =' in line:
            output[f].append(line)
        elif 'X =' in line:
            output[f].append(line)
        elif 'Y =' in line:
            output[f].append(line)
tabs = []
for tab in output:
    tabs.append(tab)

tabs.sort()
for tab in tabs:
    for row in output[tab]:
        output_file.write(row + '')
```

Now, everything is working fine, the output file looks like this:

```
ObjectID = 1216
X = -1480.500610
Y = 2610.885742
ObjectID = 970
X = -1517.210693
Y = 2522.842285
ObjectID = 3802
X = -1512.156616
Y = 2521.116210
etc.
```

But I don't want it to be like that (each value has a new line). I need it to do this for every file:

1. Read the file.
2. Remove the tags infront of the values.
3. Format a single line which will have those values in the output folder. (Let's say I want to make it look like this: "(1216,-1480.500610,2522.842285)" )
4. Write that line in the output folder.
5. Repeat for every file.

Any help please?

Comment: could you paste some sample lines from a file you need to read?

Comment: Same as output lines

Comment: I added code in which you append the values in a single line..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps.

```
data = open('sam.txt', 'r').read()

>>> print data
ObjectID = 1216
X = -1480.500610
Y = 2610.885742
ObjectID = 970
X = -1517.210693
Y = 2522.842285
ObjectID = 3802
X = -1512.156616
Y = 2521.116210
>>>
```

Now lets do some string replacements :)

```
>>> data = data.replace('ObjectID =', '').replace('\nX = ', ',').replace('\nY = ', ',')
>>> print data
 1216,-1480.500610,2610.885742
 970,-1517.210693,2522.842285
 3802,-1512.156616,2521.116210
```

Answer (score 1):

In your loop, keep track of whether you are 'in' a record:

```
records = []
in_record = False
id, x, y = 0, 0, 0
for line in txtfile:
    if not in_record:
        if 'ObjectID =' in line:
            in_record = True
            id = line[10:]
    elif 'X =' in line:
        x = line[3:]
    elif 'Y =' in line:
        y = line[3:]
        records.append((id, x, y))
        in_record = False
```

Then you'll have a list of tuples which you can easily write with the [**`csv`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module.

Comment: Now it just doesn't write anything in the file.

Comment: @M.Rox You need to write the `records` to a file.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you need. I did not have enough time to write the code for appending the result to a new file. Instead it just prints it, but you get the point.

```
import os.path

path = "path"

#getting the number of files in your folder
num_files = len([f for f in os.listdir(path)
                if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, f))])

#function that returns your desired output for a given file
def file_head_ext(file_path, file_num):
    with open(file_path + "/" + file_num) as myfile:
        head = [next(myfile).split("=") for x in range(3)]
        formatted_head = [elm[1].replace("\n",'').replace(" ","") for elm in head]
    return(",".join(formatted_head))


for filnum in range(1,num_files):
    print(file_head_ext(path, str(filnum)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Find here a version of the loop you have generating the contents.
I rewrote it so the line contents ObjectId, X and Y are in the same line.

It looks that is what you want to do:

```
for f in file_list:
    print f
    txtfile = open(f, 'r')
    output[f] = []
    for line in txtfile:
        myline = ''
        if 'ObjectID =' in line:
            pos = line.rfind("ObjectID =") + len("ObjectID =")
            rest = line[pos:]
            # Here you set the delimiter after the ObjectID value. Can be ","
            numbers = rest.split(" ")
            if len(numbers) > 0: 
                myline.append(numbers[0])

        elif 'X =' in line:
            pos = line.rfind("X =") + len("X =")
            rest = line[pos:]
            # Here you set the delimiter after the ObjectID value. Can be ","
            numbers = rest.split(" ")
            if len(numbers) > 0: 
                myline.append(numbers[0])
        elif 'Y =' in line:
            pos = line.rfind("Y =") + len("Y =")
            rest = line[pos:]
            # Here you set the delimiter after the ObjectID value. Can be ","
            numbers = rest.split(" ")
            if len(numbers) > 0: 
                myline.append(numbers[0])

        output[f].append(myline)
```

**Note** that you need to know which character (*in the code the delimiter*) separates the names you try to find: `ObjectID =` from the actual values you want to grab from the line.